# Where are getnetworkinfo localservicesnames explained?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, command-line-options, documentation

Bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo returns a list of human readable localservicesnames. Where can one find more info about them?

Comment: Hmm, the wiki lacks some of them. Updating it and will post an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list of the assigned (through the BIP process) service flags [in the wiki protocol documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#version).

The service flags supported by the reference client are defined in [src/protocol.h](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/fff7d056a92f990ebe34ee524d0f62cdf6d13193/src/protocol.h#L268-L298) .